# What does it mean "It's five to twelve"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, time

Is it 11:55? OR 12:05?
It's quite ambiguous in Korean.

Comment: In Korean, you usually say 'ten-one-hour five-ten-five minute', but you can also (less commonly) say 'before' - 'ten-two-hour five-minute-before'. (I think the rules of Stack Exchange are that I can't explain in Korean, so translate each word into Korean.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context “to” means “until”.  “30 seconds to launch and counting...”  “Only eight shopping days to Christmas!”

It’s 11:55.

Comment: This is very standard usage in British English.